# How to use pivot test to find if the following matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble using the pivot test to get to the positive definiteness of the following matrix, like in Strang's book:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Specifically, I am not sure how to get to the pivots. In this setting, I am probably not allowed to exchange the rows as that would put a minus sign in front of the determinant. But I also cannot get rid of the leading 0.

Comment: The leading zero (without zeros entries in the corresponding row/column) automatically tells you that the matrix fails the pivot test, which is to say that it is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Would you say the pivot of the first row is 0 or 1?  One confusion is that the pivot is defined not as the item on the diagonal but the first nonzero item on a row. Also, I feel the leading zero says it cannot be PD but maybe it is still PSD?

Comment: If a matrix has a $0$ as a $1,1$ entry, then if there are any non-zero entries in the first row/column then the matrix must be indefinite (neither positive nor negative semidefinite). If the entire first row/column is zero, then the matrix might be positive/negative semidefinite (but never strictly definite).

Comment: I think that Strang would call the $1$ the actual pivot of the first row in this case, but I'm not confident about his terminology in this case